# unable to fill between lines

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to create a indiactor that plot only on daily basis and include Input Tab for Enable/Disable indicator option.
But fill between two lines giving me error that says `Compilation error. Line 24: Undeclared identifier 'NT'`. Can anyone help me with this?
Here is the code

```html
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © cryptoweeknd

//@version=5
indicator ("Option Levels", overlay=true)

isToday = false
if year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time) and dayofmonth(timenow) == dayofmonth(time) 
    isToday := true

R=42491.6
S=42293.85

showNTZInput = input(true, "NO-TRADE ZONE -", inline="C1")
var color_NTR = input.color(defval=color.new(color.blue, 0), title='', inline="C1")
var color_NTS = input.color(defval=color.new(color.blue, 0), title='', inline="C1")
var in_fill = input.bool(true, "Fill", group='Option Levels', inline="C1")
var NT_colorfill = input.color(color.new(color.red, 80), "NoTrade", inline="C1")


NTR = plot(showNTZInput ? R : na, title='NoTrade', color=isToday ? color.new(color_NTR, 0) : na, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2)
NTS = plot(showNTZInput ? S : na, title='NoTrade', color=isToday ? color.new(color_NTS, 0) : na, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2)
fill(NTR, NTS, color=ta.change(NT) ? na : in_fill ? NT_colorfill : color.new(color.blue, 100))
```

Comment: Well, where is `NT` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @vitruvius

Fixed

```html
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © cryptoweeknd

//@version=5
indicator ("Option Levels", overlay=true)

isToday = false
if year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time) and dayofmonth(timenow) == dayofmonth(time) 
    isToday := true

R=42491.6
S=42293.85

showNTZInput = input(true, "NO-TRADE ZONE -", inline="C1")
var color_NTR = input.color(defval=color.new(color.blue, 0), title='', inline="C1")
var color_NTS = input.color(defval=color.new(color.blue, 0), title='', inline="C1")
var in_fill = input.bool(true, "Fill", inline="C1")
   var NT_colorfill = input.color(color.new(color.blue, 80), "NoTrade", inline="C1")



NTR = plot(showNTZInput ? R : na, title='NoTrade', color=isToday ? color.new(color_NTR, 0) : na, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2)
NTS = plot(showNTZInput ? S : na, title='NoTrade', color=isToday ? color.new(color_NTS, 0) : na, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2)
fill(NTR, NTS, color=isToday ? in_fill ? NT_colorfill : color.new(color.blue, 100) : na )
```